# can .load() in jquery Ajax method use to load an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, methods, load

can i ask can jquery ajax load method used to load an image, below is my code and it is fail, can anybody correct it?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).html("<img src='http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_wait.gif' />");
  });
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").load("http://www.google.com/images/logos/ps_logo2.png/");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button>Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Just create a `img` element, set the `src`, and place it where you wish.

```
$("div").empty().append($("<img/>", {src: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/srpr/logo1w.png"}));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HMGwZ/3/)

Comment: what i want is when loading a large image, instead of watching the image loading, i want a preloader until the image is completely load.Thanks!!

Comment: @drama, then you might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970569/slow-loading-images-best-way-to-display-temporary-image-jquery-perhaps) helpful.

Answer (score 1):

May be

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div").ajaxStart(function(){
    $(this).html("<img src='http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_wait.gif' />");
  });
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("div").html("<img src='http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_wait.gif' />");
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button>Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```